# insmod: ERROR: could not insert module kernel.ko: Invalid parameters - Error related to naming scheme of kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, netfilter

I'm using C to create a custom kernel module to hook into the netfilter operation on my Ubuntu box. However, I'm running into a problem revolving around the module_param argument. When inserting the module, I'm attempting to add a custom field, specifically this will drop ICMP traffic when specified. The code compiles fine using a standard make file but when using insmod to insert it, I get the error

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module kernel.ko: Invalid parameters
```

I'm using the command

```
insmod kernel.ko dropicmp=1
```

From what I've read, this should work with the module params argument, but nothing I've tried has fixed this.

Please find my code below.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/netdevice.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>

static struct nf_hook_ops nfho;
struct iphdr *iph;
struct tcphdr *tcp_header;
struct sk_buff *sock_buff;
unsigned int sport, dport;

// command line argument | called using insmod kernel_firewall.ko drop_icmp=1 
static int dropicmp = 1;

module_param(dropicmp, int , 0); // takes in an int from command line | (name, variable, permissions)

unsigned int hook_func(unsigned int hooknum,
                       struct sk_buff **skb,
                       const struct net_device *in,
                       const struct net_device *out,
                       int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *)){

    sock_buff = skb;

    if (!sock_buff) { // if there is no socket buffer, accept
        return NF_ACCEPT;
    }

    iph = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(sock_buff); // using the socket buffer, create our ip header structure out of packets in it

    if (!iph) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "no ip header, dropping\n"); // self explanatory
        return NF_DROP;
    }

    if(iph->protocol==IPPROTO_TCP) {
        if(iph->saddr | 0x11000000){ // if the first prefix is in the 192 range | might need to change the if statement up | considering sprintf
            printk(KERN_INFO "192 subnet detected, dropping\n");
            return NF_DROP;
        }
        else{
            return NF_ACCEPT;
        }
    }

    if(iph->protocol==IPPROTO_ICMP) { // if ICMP

        if(dropicmp == 1){
            return NF_DROP; // drop our ICMP traffic if required
        }
        else{
            return NF_ACCEPT;
        }
    }

    return NF_ACCEPT; // default to accept

}

// initialize
static int __init initialize(void) {
    nfho.hook = hook_func;
    nfho.hooknum = NF_INET_POST_ROUTING;
    nfho.pf = PF_INET;
    nfho.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;
    nf_register_hook(&nfho);
    return 0;
}

// rmmod 
static void __exit teardown(void) {
    nf_unregister_hook(&nfho);
}

module_init(initialize);
module_exit(teardown);
```

Comment: The reason for that error is almost always that the kernel you compile the module for is not the kernel you are trying to load it into.

Comment: Hmm could you expand on that a little more? I've compiled and loaded it successfully without the module_params before and it worked, only stopped when I added that.

Comment: Ah, ok, it worked without module parameter? Does it load with modparam in your code but without specifying a parameter at insmod command line? Furthermore, in your comment you state drop_icmp, but otherwise you use dropicmp, do you confuse something here?

Comment: I've tried not specifying the module parameters and it still errors out on me. That comment was from some testing last night, as it originally did have the underscore but I removed that in order to see if that was what was causing the problems. And yeah, it worked with no module parameters before, so I'm sort of lost as to why it might be erroring now. Syntax-wise this should be correct.

Comment: and `dmesg` (or the kern.log) doesn't give you any hint on what's wrong?

Comment: Update: I removed the module_param entirely and it still gives me the error that I have invalid parameters so I must have changed something else and not realized it.

Comment: What can I do to compile against the right kernel?

Comment: @Crumblez Try changing the permissions field of module_param() from 0 to 0444.

Comment: @PeterL. This did it, on top of changing the name from kernel to something else. I believe that that is a protected name so that was causing issues. Weird I was still allowed to name it that, but different issue.

Comment: Actually it was entirely due to my naming scheme, I dropped the ball hard on that...

Comment: On Stack Overflow we tend to have a questions useful for future visitors. As you have found `module_param` is *unrelated to your actual problem*, could you [edit] the question post and remove such unnecessary parts? Ideally, it should be a [mcve] which reflects the exact problem (naming the module as `kernel`).

Comment: Yep, Will do right now!

Comment: You might want to read the 'official' documentation on how to write kernel modules, starting at: [Writing Kernel Modules](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html)

Comment: regarding: `if(iph->saddr | 0x11000000)`  this is taking the `saddr` field, + a couple of other bits, and determining if the results is not 0.  Or course, with the added bits, the result will ALWAYS be no zero.  You might want to redesign this statement

Comment: @user3629249 yep, very right. I've changed that to comparing a hex string. However, one issue is I'm not sure what type the iph->saddr is. Am I comparing ints, hex, binary, char arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was all due to my dumb naming scheme... I named the module kernel... Which is obviously already in use by the kernel...... So don't do that...

Comment: Same here - don't name it 'module' either