# Cross compile Linux kernel module for Yocto distro

Tags: c++, module, kernel, yocto

I need help for building a kernel module (for the PL2303 USB-serial converter device) for a custom Yocto distribution.
What I've tried to do has been to compile the pl2303.ko binary file using bitbake and it seems to work, but when I try to load it inside the running OS (issuing the *insmod pl2303.ko* command) it gives the following error:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ko/pl2303.ko: Invalid parameters
```

Then I issue the dmesg command and this is the output:

```
[17585.849506] pl2303: disagrees about version of symbol dev_err
[17585.853980] pl2303: Unknown symbol dev_err (err -22)
```

The kernel is (*uname -a* output):

```
Linux seco-sbc-a62 4.14.78+g15a48d6 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 21 08:44:23 UTC 2019 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I've also tried to compile the sources (*pl2303.c/h*) directly on the board but it gives this error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.14.78+g15a48d6/build M=/home/root/pl2303 module modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-4.14.78'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'module'. Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-4.14.78'
make: *** [Makefile:10: all] Error 2
```

I've downloaded and unzipped this file: *linux-4.14.78.tar.gz* in */usr/src/linux-4.14.78*

== UPDATE ==
This is the Makefile content:

```
obj-m += pl2303.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Why not just install the target distribution in a VM or docker container or similar and build your code there? You can even automate that as part of your CI system.

Comment: The target distribution should run on a specific embedded device; by the way I am able to connect to the device via SSH and run the make command, the issue here is the last error "*** No rule to make target 'module'. Stop."

Comment: "module" is a very generic target name - is that one you're adding? I don't recall the Linux kernel containing such a target.

Comment: Maybe (because I am new to this kind of development) I am wrong on the Makefile writing: I've updated the question by adding the Makefile content.

Comment: Invalid parameters may mean wrong permissions to module_param. See the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49243381/insmod-error-could-not-insert-module-kernel-ko-invalid-parameters-error-rel)